# Forward results of Find command to javac

Tags: command-line, find

I wish to compile the results of a find command where the find command returns the relative filepath of a java file located in subdirectories.  E.G., I am in `./` and I want to run `javac` on a file, `someFile.java`, but I don't know at "command-type-time" what the relative path is.

Running `find . -name someFile.java` returns the correct relative path (and only the correct one so long as `someFile.java` is uniquely named within subdirectories of `.`)  I wish to compile THIS file.  So I have attempted `javac | find . -name someFile.java` but I am not sure about why this is not working.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `$()` syntax.

eg

`javac $(find ./someDir/anotherDir/ -name someFile.java)`

Comment: this worked.  i wonder, is it possible to invoke this command using Java's ProcessBuilder?  It takes commands as an array of strings and it seems that $(...) is not properly represented as one of those strings in the array.  I.E., it seems ProcessBuilder fundamentally cannot handle composite commands such as this?

Comment: That's a bash command; you'd need to run an equivalent of   bash -c "javac $(....)"   as the command to run in this case; the array would be "bash", "-c", "javac $(...)"

Answer (score 3):

Use the `exec` command of `find`:

`find . -name someFile.java -exec javac {} \;`